# MySQL Stored Procedures with parameterized arguments called from .NET TableAdapter not filtering data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, tableadapter

I am using a connection string to directly connect to my local MySql database. When I try the following:

```
Dim dtUsers As New dtUsers.UsersDataTable

Dim taUsers As New dtUsersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter

dtUsers = taUsers.GetDataByUsername_Password("useracct1", "userpw1")
```

When I look at the results of dtUsers in debugging mode, it returns all of the rows from the database and isn't filtering them to only the record with the username: useracct1 and the password: userpw1.

The stored procedures execute correctly in the MySql Workbench GUI, but for some reason, the results are not being filtered. I haven't been able to find anyone with this same issue.

MySql Stored Procedure looks like the following:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=(backtickhere)root(backtickhere)@(backtickhere)localhost(backtickhere) PROCEDURE (backtickhere)Users_ByUsername_Password(backtickhere)(IN Username VARCHAR(25),
    IN Password VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
   SELECT     ID, Email, Password, DoB, Status, SessionID, FirstName, LastName, Icon, Username, Quote, Location, ImgType, PrivateAcct, CommentNotify, TaggedNotify,
                      FollowedNotify
   FROM         Users
   WHERE     (Username = @Username) AND (Password = @Password);
END
```

Everything is also defined and setup correctly in the TableAdapter in the strongly typed DataSet.

Comment: Maybe a look at the generated function GetDataByUserName_password might clue us in

Comment: Thanks for surrounding my code with quotes. That GetDataByUserName_Password is a function that is built from the stored procedure mentioned above (Users_ByUsername_Password). What would you like me to try?

Comment: What are you using to create the stored procedure?